# Fibers of period map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, hodge-theory

Consider the period map for some smooth varieties, $p:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}:X\mapsto J(X)$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is moduli space of certain varieties and $\mathcal{A}$ is moduli space of Polarized abelian varieties, and $J(X)$ is intermediate Jacobian of $X$.  If $p$ is injective, then we say Torelli theorem holds for $X$.

My question is if Torelli theorem does not hold and the fiber of period map has positive dimension, is it possible that fibers over different points do not have the same dimension? Is it possible the fibers over different points have equal dimension but those fibers are different varieties? For example, the general fiber is a surface but the special fiber is also a surface but a different surface. Any known example for both questions?

Comment: You can “engineer” these things by choosing $X$ to be a blowing up of projective space along an embedded curve.

Comment: If $\mathcal{X}$ is allowed to be disconnected (e.g., moduli of some surfaces of general type with fixed invariants), then it can be injective on some pos-dim'l component and constant on another (for example).